# Is there any way to change input method on .NET Compact Framework 2.0

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce, ime

I'm developing a Windows Mobile application in C#, .NET Compact Framework 2.0.
Installed OS is Windows Mobile 6.0.

The problem is when I input some text on a Textbox using physical keyboard,
Korean is typed always because OS is Korean window mobile.
So, I try to change IME mode to English programmatically but there is no method in the Framework.
For example

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.ImeMode = ImeMode.Alpha; // CF does't support this property
```

Of course once I change the mode using soft keyboard on the screen, it works in English but I don't want to use one.

I want to know the method exactly same works like the code above.

Somebody help me~~

Comment: So you want a program that says "I don't care what language you want your phone in, you have to interact with me in ENglish"?

Comment: I mean I want to change the IME when I want programmatically.

Comment: I guess you could turn it off or DIsable it from your program, but the core of what I see here is you want it to be English when the user is in another language. Not sure that is wise.

Comment: The outome of the keypad is defined by the keypad driver programmer. To get a different output you need to ask the manufactorer of the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr ImmGetContext(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    public static extern Boolean ImmReleaseContext(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    public static extern Boolean ImmSetConversionStatus(IntPtr hIMC, Int32 fdwConversion, Int32 fdwSentence);

    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    public static extern Boolean ImmSetOpenStatus(IntPtr hIMC, Int32 fOpen);

    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 ImmAssociateContext(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 hIMC);

    public enum ImeMode { 
        NOCONTROL = 0,
        OFF = 1,
        ON = 2,
        DISABLE = 3,
        KOREAFULL = 4,
        KOREA = 5,
        ALPHAFULL = 6,
        ALPHA = 7
        };

    Int32 ALPHANUMERIC = 0x0; 
    Int32 NATIVE = 0x1;
    Int32 FULLSHAPE = 0x8;
    Int32 ROMAN = 0x10;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SetImeMode(Control ctrl, ImeMode mode)
    {
        IntPtr himc = ImmGetContext(ctrl.Handle);
        Int32 dwConversion = 0;

        try
        {
            switch (mode)
            {
                case ImeMode.DISABLE:
                    ImmAssociateContext(himc, 0);
                    break;
                case ImeMode.OFF:
                    ImmAssociateContext(himc, 1);
                    ImmSetOpenStatus(himc, 0);
                    break;
                case ImeMode.ON:
                    ImmAssociateContext(himc, 1);
                    ImmSetOpenStatus(himc, 1);
                    break;
                case ImeMode.KOREAFULL:
                    dwConversion = NATIVE | FULLSHAPE | ROMAN;
                    ImmSetConversionStatus(himc, dwConversion, 0);
                    break;
                case ImeMode.KOREA:
                    dwConversion = NATIVE | ROMAN;
                    ImmSetConversionStatus(himc, dwConversion, 0);
                    break;
                case ImeMode.ALPHAFULL:
                    dwConversion = FULLSHAPE | ALPHANUMERIC;
                    ImmSetConversionStatus(himc, dwConversion, 0);
                    break;
                case ImeMode.ALPHA:
                    dwConversion = ALPHANUMERIC;
                    ImmSetConversionStatus(himc, dwConversion, 0);
                    break;
            }                
        }
        finally
        {
            ImmReleaseContext(ctrl.Handle);
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetImeMode(textBox1, ImeMode.KOREA);
    }

}
```